# Eliminar espacios en arraylist JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy elaborando un programa para llevar un inventariado de mis colecciones. Para ello una de las funciones que utilizo es 'Buscar en archivo'. Se me ocurrió que los ítems los tendré guardados en un txt del siguiente modo:

```
    OBJETO    ||    CANTIDAD    ||    DESCRIPCIÓN

  Camisetas            12            Son talla X y de color Y
```

A la hora de Buscar se me ocurrió cargar todo el fichero en un ArrayList y eliminar la primera fila:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file)));
items.remove(0);
```

Querría saber como puedo eliminar los primeros espacios antes de Camisetas.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Para remover espacios al principio y al final de un string, usa `String.trim()`

Comment: Hay alguna manera de eliminarlos en todos los elementos del ArrayList sin necesidad de hacerlo en un bucle con items.get(1).trim();? @Benito-B

Comment: La respuesta tiene muchas más líneas de explicación que código, pero bueno xD boas noites :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe efectivamente una manera de hacerlo en una sola línea, aquí te dejo un ejemplo con las explicaciones en los comentarios:

```
// Lista de strings con espacios de más
List<String> categories = Arrays.asList("  Camisetas ", "   Cds    ", "    Videojuegos    ");
/* Esta línea es un poco raruna tal vez, pero es la manera más corta de hacer lo que quieres!
 * Basicamente estoy pidiéndole que haga un replaceAll pasándole el método trim a todos. Esto se llama
 * Method reference y es lo mismo que hacer categories.replaceAll(category -> category.trim()).
 * Cuando solo vas a llamar a un método en donde podrías poner una lambda, es posible simplemente pasar
 * el método que quieres ejecutar y java automaticamente lo aplicará a cada elemento. Es decir, recorrerá la
 * lista aplicando trim() a cada string!
 */
categories.replaceAll(String::trim);
//El resultado de esto es [Camisetas, Cds, Videojuegos]
System.out.println(categories);
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias